# Uninstall programs that are not visible in Application manager

Tags: applications, 5.0-lollipop, file-system

I have an Asus Nexus 7 that is full of games that take up all 29 GB of memory. The kids installed these games, and they are not visible in the Application Manager. Perhaps they were installed in a different way. I found an OBB directory that contains a lot of gigantic files with the extension `obb` and names that are related to games, but I'm not sure whether I can delete them without damaging the system. Where I should start to find and remove games?

Comment: OK, getting closer. Now just to check what you mean by "application manager", as some manufacturers ship such for their own apps/stores. Starting from the home-screen, check *Settings › Apps,* and in there select the *Downloaded* tab. That should list all apps installed by "the user", regardless of by what means. Is this what you're talking about? If not, are the apps you want to get rid of listed there?

Comment: I'm talking about "Starting from the home-screen, check Settings › Apps, and in there select the Downloaded tab"

Comment: If "user-installed apps" are not listed here, they're usually no longer installed (and the "big chunk of data" thus must be left-overs from some "unclean uninstallation"). To verify, you can use a terminal app or, better, `adb shell` from the computer, and run `pm list packages -3`. This lists all user-installed apps using their *package names*. To know what the "app name" behind them is, you can e.g. visit their app-page at Google Play: `https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=<package_name>`. If the corresponding apps are not listed here either, they're definitely no longer installed.

Comment: Do the kids have their own profile on the Nexus 7? If so, have you checked the applications from there? There's no way for apps that are installed to not be listed in the Apps list in settings. But it is possible for the apps, if not installed, to have left file remnants behind. We'll address that after your other answers, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use alternative application managers available from the Play store, or even Titanium Backup if you are rooted.

secondly if you are rooted,

1. Download any root explorer,
2. Navigate to /system/app/ or sometimes /system/priv-app/ and manually
   uninstall by deleting the packages (you may need to delete files
   from android folder manually eg. obb files)
3. Reboot and you are done (optional)

If none of the above works,

1. Do a backup of apps and data using a backup manager (Recommended:
   [Helium](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.koushikdutta.backup) for non root users, [Titanium Backup](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup) for root users)
2. factory reset the phone, and delete '.androidsecure' and 'Android'
   folder from external memory if exists.

Voila! you are done!